# Hard drive wipe on Windows 10 revert to Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, data-recovery

My grandfather bought a Windows 7 machine a few years ago; about a month or so ago, it updated to Windows 10 (he was not expecting this, but I expect he clicked an update button without realising what it would do).

Today, the computer has reverted back to Windows 7, and appears to have deleted all his files and applications in the process (so that it looks like a clean Windows 7 machine). Now, I don't know how this happened, but given that it *has* happened, is there a viable route to data recovery?

Comment: **Most Likely Scenario:** Your grandpa clicked to upgrade to Windows 10. When the update prompt comes up, it gives you an option to upgrade and keep files, or upgrade with a clean install. I assume he picked the clean install and updated to Windows 10. After the update to Windows 10, you have 30 days to revert back to Windows 7. With the clean install, the drive it's installed on is wiped clean. **Best Case Senario:** He did the Windows upgrade, then downgrade and there is a `Windows.old` folder on the `C:` drive that should hopefully contain his data.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help. But his data was there after the Windows 10 update, so I assume he didn't click the 'clean install' option? Also, sadly there is no Windows.old folder. Weird!

Comment: You have asked multiple questions. Please edit your post to **one** specific question. As written, it is too broad and can have many answers.

Comment: Super User focuses on questions that have a definitive answer.  For the situation you describe, people can only guess at what might have transpired because there are a number of ways the computer could have ended up in that general state.  Questions that ask for speculation on what happened are considered too broad or opinion-based.  Your real question at this point is how to recover, so edit your question to focus on that.  The answer depends on what happened, but there are only a couple of recovery scenarios, so that would be more in-scope.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've edited the question in light of your remarks; I hope this is more acceptable.

Comment: If your question is about recovering the files (not the OS), check out my answer to a similar question here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283009/84179

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if OEM recovery was used. Īt usually comes preinstalled on a hidden HDD partition and contains clean Windows with integrated OEM drivers.
It may be started from BIOS startup screen by function key.

Comment: So how does the author solve their problem?  This seems more like a comment to be honest.

Comment: @Ramhound In all fairness, the OP asked multiple questions, of which one was "*Does anyone have any idea how this could have happened?*" Nevertheless, this is an incomplete answer because it does not resolve the problem.

Comment: @CharlieRB - I was giving the author the benefit of the doubt that they actually know how to solve the author's problem.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I was simply pointing out that this new user chose to answer one or many questions asked. Perfect example of why there should not be multiple questions to a post.